# Why 'debugger' will prevent event(keydown -> onInput) be fired

Tags: javascript, events, browser, ecmascript-6, dom-events

We know that if we add both `input` and `keyDown` listener to one dom, when we type something, it will trigger `keyDown`, and then trigger `input`.

But if we add a debugger in the `keyDown` handler, you will find that it won't trigger the `input` handler, it will just trigger the `keyDown` handler (test in Chrome and Safari)

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keydown', function(){
 debugger;
  
  alert('keyDown')
})

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('input', function(){
 debugger;
  
  alert('input')
})
```

```html
<input id="foo" />
```

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: It triggers both on Chrome 62.

Comment: Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit), Linux - Only one triggers

Comment: @HristoKolev you'll need to have Dev Tools open for this to work

Comment: @domenic Hi, do you have any thought about this?

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting.

Conversely, if the `keydown` event is changed to `keyup`, only the `input` event (and alert) is triggered.

By adding a few `console.log()`s I think I have an idea of what's happening. Additional insight is definitely welcomed however.

**tldr;** The presence of the `debugger` on the `keydown` prevents the value from the `keydown` event from being input, which means the value of the input is never changed, which means the `input` event is never triggered.

In the example below, the `debugger` is triggered on the `keydown` event, which happens before the value is inserted. The debugger pauses the execution, and any resulting events, preventing the value from being inserted. When the debugger is resumed the input is never updated with the new value, hence the `input` event is never triggered. You can see this on the example below - if you open Dev Tools and try to enter a value into the input, then click Resume on the debugger, you'll see the value is never inserted into to the input. So the `input` event would never be triggered.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  
  debugger;
  console.log(e.target.value, 'keyDown')
  
})

document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  
  debugger;
  console.log(e.target.value, 'input')
})
```

```html
<input id="foo" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I thinks this is a reasonable explanation

Comment: @SmallTownNE don't forget to accept the solution the answers your question.

Comment: Let's keep it open, because we don't sure it's the right answer, if possible I would invite someone which work for browsers to answer this :)